# POST json data with cURL from a while loop - bash shell

Tags: bash, curl, json

I have a JSON output from which I need to extract an ID and Iterate through them and send multiple request to API execute REST API with curl.
For example:

This is how the JSON output looks like:

```
{
    "glossary": [
        {
            "Title": "example glossary1",
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Hello Glossary1"
        },
        {
            "Title": "example glossary2",
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Hello Glossary2"
        },
        {
            "Title": "example glossary3",
            "id": 3,
            "description": "Hello Glossary3"
        },
        {
            "Title": "example glossary4",
            "id": 4,
            "description": "Hello Glossary4"
        }
    ]
}
```

The shell script should loop through this JSON file, extract the ID and loop through and execute REST API calls with CURL.

Here is example:

```
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#id[@]} ; i++ ))
do 
     POST REST API 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have you output in a file called tmp.json use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to get the list of ids, one per line and then with a simple for loop make a post to your api

```
for i in `cat tmp.json  | jq .glossary[].id`; do 
   curl -X POST http://host/api/$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, just using `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for id in $(awk '/"id":/ {sub(/,/, ""); print $2}' inputfile.json); do
    curl -X POST ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Without awk up to 3 digit ids. Just push your JSON result through STDIN and read with a while loop:

```
digits=0; 
while read line
do 
  foo=`echo $line|grep id|cut -c 7-$((7+digits))`
  if [[ ! $foo -eq '' ]]
    then 
      echo "curl http://webaddress/api?id=$foo"
      if [[ '$foo' == '9' ]] || [[ '$foo' == '99' ]]
      then 
        digits=$((digits+1)) 
      fi 
  fi 
done<your-json-output.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl allows you to make several requests to the same endpoint at once by using curly braces (`{...}`) in the URL.

For example, if your endpoint is

```
http://example.com/api/endpoint
```

then you may call this with three values of some parameter `id` like so:

```bash
curl 'http://example.com/api/endpoint?id={123,345,456}'
```

To get the IDs out of your JSON document as a comma-delimited set of integers in curly braces, use `jq` like so:

```bash
jq -r '.glossary | map(.id) | "{\(join(","))}"' file
```

For the given document in the question, this would return the string `{1,2,3,4}`.

You may then use this in your single call to `curl`:

```bash
ids=$( jq -r '.glossary | map(.id) | "{\(join(","))}"' file )

curl -s "http://example.com/api/endpoint?id=$ids"
```